# How to get details of CPU/RAM/Storage from ESXi Server using pyVmomi?

Tags: python-2.7, pyvmomi

I want to extract the CPU/RAM/Storage details of hosts from a vcenter using pyvmomi.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyvmomi Get RAM/CPU Usage VSphere SDK 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502855/pyvmomi-get-ram-cpu-usage-vsphere-sdk-5-5)